# Issue with Slide-Out Menu Navigation In Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I followed [This](http://www.appdesignvault.com/custom-transition-slide-out-navigation/) tutorial and achieve that animation but now I want to add some functionality into it like when user click in the minimised `viewController` I want to popup that minimised `viewController` back I tried to Implement TapGesture on that view and this is my code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TransitionOperator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate{

var snapshot : UIView!
var isPresenting : Bool = true

func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> NSTimeInterval {
    return 0.5
}


func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    if isPresenting{
        presentNavigation(transitionContext)
    }else{
        dismissNavigation(transitionContext)
    }
}

func presentNavigation(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let container = transitionContext.containerView()
    let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)
    let fromView = fromViewController!.view
    let toViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)
    let toView = toViewController!.view

    let size = toView.frame.size
    var offSetTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(size.width - 120, 0)
    offSetTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(offSetTransform, 0.6, 0.6)

    snapshot = fromView.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)

    //TapGesture for detect touch
    let aSelector : Selector = "singleTap"
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: aSelector)
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.snapshot.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    container.addSubview(toView)
    container.addSubview(snapshot)

    let duration = self.transitionDuration(transitionContext)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: nil, animations: {

        self.snapshot.transform = offSetTransform

        }, completion: { finished in

            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
    })

}
func singleTap(){

    NavigationViewController().dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    println("Touched")

}

func dismissNavigation(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    let container = transitionContext.containerView()
    let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)
    let fromView = fromViewController!.view
    let toViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)
    let toView = toViewController!.view

    let duration = self.transitionDuration(transitionContext)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: nil, animations: {

        self.snapshot.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

        }, completion: { finished in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
            self.snapshot.removeFromSuperview()
    })
}

func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {

    self.isPresenting = true
    return self
}

func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {

    self.isPresenting = false
    return self
   }
}
```

when I click on that minimised view `Touched` is print as you can see into image:

[image]

But view is not dismissed.I want to popup `TimelineViewController` back.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use **https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController** classes for create slide view

Comment: Have you figured out the solution to this? I have the same issue. I am also trying to add functionality such that the user can use the slide gesture instead of having to click the menu bar icon in the top left corner.

Comment: nop still I didnt found solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need to do is call self.dismissNavigation() from your singleTap method. Though I'm not sure what context to pass to that method...

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what should I pass into self.dismissNavigation()?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a few months but i figured it out. Look at the function `animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController)` which has the parameter `presented`, the `UIViewController` of the snapshot. That is your reference that you need instead of calling `NavigationViewController().` which is just making new instances. So create a `UIView` variable `var foo : UIView!` and in `animationControllerForPresentedController()` set `foo = presented`.

Now in your function `singleTap()` you can set `foo.dismissViewControllerAnimated()`.

Hope this helps.